# In python, What does it mean if I assign a variable to a method?

Tags: python, cherrypy, metaobject

Reading the CherryPy tutorial I run into this

```
class HelloWorld(object):
    def index(self):
        return "Hello World!"
    index.exposed = True
```

So was does it mean? is exposed a variable in the local scope of the method index? If so, can I the value of expose change? I think it has something to do with python's MetaObject protocol to expose a class definition as an object itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not a local variable of function index, rather it's a attribute of that function .
And yes you can modify it outside the function too.

Read the [PEP 232](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0232/) on function attributes.

example:

```
In [2]: def foo():pass
   ...: 

In [3]: foo.bar="text"

In [4]: foo.bar
Out[4]: 'text'
```

Answer (score 4):

Functions are first-class objects in Python.  A function definition creates a function object and binds it to the function's name.  Function objects can have attributes, and that's what you are seeing here.  The life time of a function attribute is bound the the life time of the function object, while the life time of a local variable inside the function is bound to a single execution of the function.  They are completely separate.